# How can I inject for generic inherited types?

Tags: java, cdi, weld, weld-se, weld-junit5

I spent a plenty of time for finding any answers, but I think I have to ask.

I'm using Weld-SE for testing my entities.

I prepared entity randomizer for testing.

```java
abstract class BaseEntityRandomizer<T extends BaseEntity>
        implements Randomizer<T> {

    @Override public T getRandomValue() {
        ...
    }
}

class MySomeOtherEntityRandomizer
        extends BaseEntityRandomizer<MySomeOther> {

    @Override public MySomeOther getRandomValue() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, with my test class, I want to inject those randomizers which each matches generic parameters

```java
@ExtendWith(WeldJunit5Extension.class)
@AddPackages({BaseEntityRandomizer.class})
abstract class BaseEntityTest<T extends BaseEntity> {

    @Test void doSome() {
    }

    @Inject
    private BaseEntityRandomizer<T> entityRandomizer;
}

class MySomeOtherTest extends BaseEntityTest<MySomeOther> {
    ...
    // I expect an instance of MySomeOtherRandomizer in injected
    // into the entityRandomizer field.
}
```

Subclasses of randomizers and tests are prepared.

But I failed to make it work.

How can I make it work?

I tried with following factory class

```java
class BaseEntityRandomizerFactory {

   @Produces
   public BaseEntityRandomizer<MySome> produceMySomeRandomizer() {
        return new MySomeRandomizer();
   }
}
```

I got

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: 
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type BaseEntityRandomizer<T extends BaseEntity> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected transient ....BaseEntityTest.entityRandomizer
  at ....BaseEntityTest.entityRandomizer(BaseEntityTest.java:0)
```

Comment: So you are trying to inject a general superclass and then select multiple given impls in the test? For that I feel `@Inject Instance<Object>` might work with subsequent calls to `select()` and `get()`. Or is it something else you are trying to achieve? Can you share the actual problem? It is not injecting anything or is there ambiguous dependency?

Comment: @Siliarus I updated my question for you, Thanks.

Comment: @Siliarus I insist you to make your comment as answer. I wasted a half a day why my `Instance<T>` doesn't work. And the `Instance<Object>` saved my life.

Comment: I've created a short answer from my comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use [CDI Programmatic lookup](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#programmatic_lookup). In your case, I'd start with `@Inject Instance<Object>` and then you can use subsequent calls to `select()` and `get()` methods to pick up whichever bean you desire. Usage looks something like this (assumes existence of beans with types `Foo`, `Bar` and `List<String>`):

```
    @Inject
    private Instance<Object> instance;
    
    @Test void doSome() {
      // selecting and obtaining instances of beans
      Foo foo = entityRandomizer.select(Foo.class).get();
      Bar bar = entityRandomizer.select(Bar.class).get();
      // in case you need to select a parameterized type from instance, use TypeLiteral
      List<String> listBean = entityRandomized..select( new TypeLiteral<List<String>>(){}).get()
    }
```